# Do I need to specify a return type for an anonymous function in javascript / typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following function:

```
    $('td:eq(' + iColumn + ') input', oSettings.oApi._fnGetTrNodes(oSettings))
        .each(function () {
            aData.push(this.value);
         });
```

In typescript I am getting a message saying:

```
Error   3   Function declared a non-void return type, but has no return expression
```

Why am I getting this message? I can resolve the message by saying "return true". Should I always specify a return type for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The signature of `.each()` in the `jquery.d.ts` file on the typescript repository is:

```
each(func: (index: any, elem: Element) => JQuery);
```

The jQuery documentation says that

> We can stop the loop from within the callback function by returning false.

which implies that this `jquery.d.ts` is wrong.

If you grab an updated version from [Boris Yankov's repository](https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/Definitions), it will become:

```
each(func: (index: any, elem: Element) => any);
```

This form will allow you to return anything, or nothing.